# Why Request URL changes after the react app is built and deployed?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am building a react app(with create-react-app) which gets and post data from the server built with django. I am using axios for API request with react.js.

It works well in development mode but when I build the react app and deploy to netlify, the request url changes. In development phase, Network of developer tools of Chrome shows `Request URL: https://xyz.herokuapp.com/abc/` but when I build the app and deploy to the netlify it shows `Request URL: https://loving-dijkstra-99eada.netlify.com/xyz.herokuapp.com/abc/` and API call fails.  Axios code for the api call is:

```
axios.get('https:xyz.herokuapp.com/abc/')
       .then((res) => {
         console.log("successfully received the page count", res.data);
       }).catch((err) => {
         console.log(err, 'error  in the get of data');
       });
```

How to make this working? package.json is here.

```
{
  "name": "now-ui-kit-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.25.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "nouislider": "14.0.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap-switch": "15.5.3",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-router": "5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "8.0.1",
    "validator": "^12.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.css --source-map true"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a double slash in the protocol.

```
axios.get('https:xyz.herokuapp.com/abc/')
```

Should be

```
axios.get('https://xyz.herokuapp.com/abc/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract your server files to the root file. 
In your case, you probably have a folder with the name `xyz.herokuapp.com`, and that is the reason for the wrong path and wrong request from Axios...